# Unfortunately app has stopped on android emulator

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my main.java

```
package com.example.citylife;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btn7=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hotels.class);
            startActivity(obj1);

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Cabs.class);
            startActivity(obj2);

        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj3=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hospitals.class);
            startActivity(obj3);

        }
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj4=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Monuments.class);
            startActivity(obj4);

        }
    });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj5=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Theatres.class);
            startActivity(obj5);

        }
    });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj6=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Malls.class);
            startActivity(obj6);

        }
    });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent obj7=new       Intent(MainActivity.this,ExpenseCalculator.class);
            startActivity(obj7);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is my main.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnCount="1"
android:rowCount="12" 
android:background="@color/skyblue">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="HOTELS" 
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="CABS" 
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="HOSPITALS" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="MONUMENTS" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:text="THEATRES" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:text="MALLS" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:text="EXPENSE CALCULATOR" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/darkblue"/>
```

When i click on expense calculator, unfortunately app has stopped appears whose main and xml file are given below

```
package com.example.citylife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpenseCalculator extends Activity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6,ed7;
Button btn1,btn2;
TextView tt1,tt2;
int a1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
int b2=Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
int c3=Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
int d4=Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
int e5=Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
int f6=Integer.parseInt(ed6.getText().toString());
int g7=Integer.parseInt(ed7.getText().toString());
int total = a1 + b2 + c3 + d4 + e5 + f6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_calculator);
    ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    ed5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ed6=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    ed7=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tt2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tt1.setText(Integer.toString(total));

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(g7>total)
            tt2.setText("Go for it !!");
        else
            tt2.setText("Out of budget :(");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.expense_calculator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="26" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="10"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="CABS:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:text="HOSPITALS:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:text="MONUMENTS:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:text="THEATRES:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="10"
    android:text="MALLS:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="HOTELS:" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_row="20"
    android:text="Total Expenses" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_row="21"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_row="21"
    android:text="Your Budget"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_row="24"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Check" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_row="20"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="21dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:layout_row="24"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="21dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Log cat is:

```
06-26 15:47:49.540: D/gralloc_goldfish(1001): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-26 15:47:54.660: D/AndroidRuntime(1001): Shutting down VM
06-26 15:47:54.660: W/dalvikvm(1001): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a1dba8)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): Process: com.example.citylife, PID: 1001
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citylife/com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator.<init>(ExpenseCalculator.java:17)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-26 15:47:54.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1001):     ... 11 more
06-26 15:48:04.230: I/Process(1001): Sending signal. PID: 1001 SIG: 9
```

I am new to android app development and can't understand why this error is coming
Please help!!!

Here is the new logcat after doing corrections given by 1st answer:

```
06-27 12:41:17.694: D/gralloc_goldfish(959): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 12:41:37.944: D/dalvikvm(959): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 11% free 2625K/2928K, paused 8ms+27ms, total 184ms
06-27 12:41:38.084: D/AndroidRuntime(959): Shutting down VM
06-27 12:41:38.094: W/dalvikvm(959): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citylife/com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator.onCreate(ExpenseCalculator.java:30)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-27 12:41:38.144: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 11 more
06-27 12:41:45.854: I/Process(959): Sending signal. PID: 959 SIG: 9
```

logcat after putting null checker:

```
06-27 13:39:10.275: D/gralloc_goldfish(2013): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 13:43:57.694: D/dalvikvm(2013): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 11% free 2598K/2920K, paused 7ms+34ms, total 259ms
06-27 13:43:57.844: D/AndroidRuntime(2013): Shutting down VM
06-27 13:43:57.844: W/dalvikvm(2013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citylife/com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator.onCreate(ExpenseCalculator.java:30)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-27 13:43:57.914: E/AndroidRuntime(2013):     ... 11 more
06-27 13:44:03.124: I/Process(2013): Sending signal. PID: 2013 SIG: 9
06-27 13:59:01.284: D/gralloc_goldfish(2367): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 13:59:25.764: D/dalvikvm(2367): GC_CONCURRENT freed 169K, 11% free 2620K/2920K, paused 9ms+28ms, total 273ms
06-27 13:59:25.974: D/AndroidRuntime(2367): Shutting down VM
06-27 13:59:25.974: W/dalvikvm(2367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citylife/com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at  java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator.onCreate(ExpenseCalculator.java:31)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-27 13:59:26.044: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     ... 11 more
06-27 13:59:31.525: I/Process(2367): Sending signal. PID: 2367 SIG: 9
```

new logcat:

```
06-27 14:16:09.574: D/gralloc_goldfish(2726): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 14:18:48.964: D/dalvikvm(2726): GC_CONCURRENT freed 170K, 11% free 2611K/2912K, paused 10ms+30ms, total 209ms
06-27 14:18:49.036: D/AndroidRuntime(2726): Shutting down VM
06-27 14:18:49.044: W/dalvikvm(2726): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citylife/com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.example.citylife.ExpenseCalculator.onCreate(ExpenseCalculator.java:43)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-27 14:18:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     ... 11 more
06-27 14:18:57.084: I/Process(2726): Sending signal. PID: 2726 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You are trying to convert an empty value "" to a number, the Stacktrace leads you to the exact answer and line of code (it is important to know how to read a stack, worth reading up about).

Comment: ExpenseCalculator.java:30 - this tells me the Class, and the line number where this is happenning.

Comment: i have initialised all int variables to zero, still the error persists :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is Edittext is null when you retrieving the value from it. You haven't assigned the view to it yet.

Just move the code to retrieve the value after you assign the view as shown in code below.

```
public class ExpenseCalculator extends Activity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6,ed7;
Button btn1,btn2;
TextView tt1,tt2;
int a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,f6,g7; //these variables will be assigned 0
//Removed the code from here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_calculator);
    ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    ed5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ed6=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    //added the code here after ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6 is assigned
    if(!ed1.getText().toString().equals(""))
    a1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
    if(!ed2.getText().toString().equals(""))
    b2=Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
    if(!ed3.getText().toString().equals(""))
    c3=Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
    if(!ed4.getText().toString().equals(""))
    d4=Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
    if(!ed5.getText().toString().equals(""))
    e5=Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
    if(!ed6.getText().toString().equals(""))
    f6=Integer.parseInt(ed6.getText().toString());
    if(!ed7.getText().toString().equals(""))
    g7=Integer.parseInt(ed7.getText().toString());
    int total = a1 + b2 + c3 + d4 + e5 + f6;
```

Comment: The  new error is because you are not entering value in one of the edittext. Ensure you enter value in all the edittext. If value is not entered by default value is "" and integer cannot take ""

Comment: i have edited my question and pasted the log at last, check it please

Comment: I have applied gettext on all edittext variables, so there is no edittext box which wont take value

Comment: i have put the logcat in question, please check it

Comment: you have to move the declaration a1,b2,..etc above onCreate as shown in my answer. I believe you havent done that. That would cause the variable to have 0 if nothing is assigned to it.
`int a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,f6,g7;`

Comment: still the error man :( , please help me :(, again i have put the logcat

Comment: Which line is the error with..post the line associated with the error

Comment: i dont know where does the line number show in logcat, i am new to android app dev, so i dont know in which line is the error but there are no red crosses anywhere at any line, that i can assure

Comment: I belive its better to post another question for the new issue so that you get other users attention. Your initial issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your int variables to 0.
So that even though, your edittext is empty, you'll have a default value.

Or do some checking with the value first before doing any kind of data manipulation.

```
public class ExpenseCalculator extends Activity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6,ed7;
Button btn1,btn2;
TextView tt1,tt2;

//initialize to zero
int a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,f6,g7,total = 0;

/* this code below already takes input from edit text during intialization of code hence it's probably null

int a1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
int b2=Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
int c3=Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
int d4=Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
int e5=Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
int f6=Integer.parseInt(ed6.getText().toString());
int g7=Integer.parseInt(ed7.getText().toString());
int total = a1 + b2 + c3 + d4 + e5 + f6;
*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_calculator);
    ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    ed4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    ed5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ed6=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    ed7=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tt2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tt1.setText(Integer.toString(total));

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //getting the input only when button clicked
          a1=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
          b2=Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
          c3=Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
          d4=Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
          e5=Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
          f6=Integer.parseInt(ed6.getText().toString());
          g7=Integer.parseInt(ed7.getText().toString());
          total = a1 + b2 + c3 + d4 + e5 + f6;

        if(g7>total)
            tt2.setText("Go for it !!");
        else
            tt2.setText("Out of budget :(");

        }
    });
}
```